# Cannot send email from godaddy smtp using classic asp - going mad

Tags: asp-classic, smtp

I am really struggling with something which is pretty basic and need some help as it was not forthcoming from godaddy support!

For some reason the code below is not sending out any emails.

Code seems to be executed property and riddled it with lots of debug msgs but to no helping!

Te "From" email address is valid and has no issues! Any ideas? Port?

cheers, Jay

```
<%

Dim objNewMail
Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objNewMail.From = "info@example.com" 
objNewMail.To   = "info@example.com" 
objNewMail.Subject = "Interesting property sent by xxx"
objNewMail.TextBody = "Click the following link to see the property :" '& vbcr & vbcr & "http://www.maltawide.eu/default.asp?pid="

' GoDaddy SMTP Settings
'I had to remove the smpt settings as I dont have enough rep to post two links!

Response.Write ("Message sent successfully!")

%>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your message failed, but here is code from a working mail form hosted at GoDaddy. All you need to do is build the form page to submit the form fields used in the script, or change the form field names in the script to match your existing form, or replace the forms with strings. Examples of both form entry and assigned variable values are included in the example's ' Create the message part of the code.

```
<%
Dim strBody
Dim strToAddress
Dim strFromAddress
Dim strReplyAddress
Dim strBlindCC

' Create the message
strBody = Request.Form("Message")
strToAddress = Request.Form("ToAddress")
strFromAddress = Request.Form("FromAddress")
strReplyAddress  = "NoReply@WebSite.com"
strBlindCC = "BlindCC@WebSite.com"  



' Include the schemas
sendUrl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
smtpUrl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"


' Set the mail server configuration
Set objConfig=CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
objConfig.Fields.Item(sendUrl)=2 ' cdoSendUsingPort
objConfig.Fields.Item(smtpUrl)="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
objConfig.Fields.Update


' Send the message
Set objMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objMail.Configuration=objConfig

objMail.From=strFromAddress 
objMail.ReplyTo=strReplyAddress

objMail.To=strToAddress

objMail.BCC=strBlindCC

objMail.Subject=strSubject

objMail.HTMLBody = strBody

objMail.Send

%>
```

Comment: No joy I am afraid! I have copied/pasted your text and replaced the variables but nothing! very strange indeed.

Comment: Can you copy your current code? If you do, I'll try it on my GODaddy server to see why it is failing. What error messages do you get?

Comment: thanks Charles. Not sure I can copy the current code as a comment so will edit the original message! I have narrowed down the problem to two issues one with the from address (for some reason info(a)maltawide.eu which is hosted at godaddy does not work) and two is trying to paste a link in the msg body. see code above.

Comment: I have created a new question here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042035/how-to-send-a-url-in-a-msg-body-using-classic-asp-godaddy